# SQL update column 2 and column 3 from value of column 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write an sql update which, will update 2 columns in every row taking value from other column.
For example i have a table

`Column 1` |`Column 2` | `column 3`

`Value 1`   |`nothing XX`|`nothing`

`VaLUE 2` |`nothing XX`|`nothing`

`Value 3` | `nothing XX`|`nothing`

i want to update column 2 and column 3 from value of column 1.
The result table should be like this:

`Column 1` |`Column 2` | `column 3`

`Value 1`   |`Value 1`|`Value 1`

`VaLUE 2` |`VaLUE 2`|`VaLUE 2`

`Value 3` | `Value 3`|`Value 3`

Any ideas?

Comment: Store the same value in several columns?!? Why?

Answer (score 2):

Seems completely pointless to make all three columns the same but the code is super simple.

```
Update SomeTable
set Column2 = column1
, Column3 = Column1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update table set
   [Column 2] = [Column 1],
   [Column 3] = [Column 1]
```

but why?  if you just need more than one output column to contain the same value, better is to create computed column

```
  Alter table [MyTable] add [column2] as column1
```

this will show in a `select *` as an additional column, but the data is not persisted twice.